# Capture value of the listitem <MenuItem> React mui/material

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to capture the value of selected item given below:

I am trying to console this :

```
console.log("Event: ", event.currentTarget);
```

Output:

```
<li class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters MuiMenuItem-root MuiMenuItem-gutters css-155lmgu-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiMenuItem-root" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" value="software developer"><div class="MuiListItemIcon-root css-8k0q8y-MuiListItemIcon-root"></div><div class="MuiListItemText-root css-tlelie-MuiListItemText-root"><p class="MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 MuiListItemText-primary css-1s4zgv0-MuiTypography-root">software developer</p></div><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-8je8zh-MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></li>
```

And

```
console.log("Event: ", event.currentTarget.value);
```

Output: Event: undefined

This is how I am trying to pass the value:

```
<MenuItem sx={{ color: 'text.secondary' }} value={ContentTitle.contentTitle} onClick={onSelectedContentTitle}>
                    <ListItemIcon></ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText primary={ContentTitle.contentTitle} primaryTypographyProps={{ variant: 'body2' }} />
                </MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log("Event: ", event.currentTarget.outerText);
```

This figured it out for me.